# table border thickness with UseVariableBorders set to true

Tags: pdf, itext

I’m using iTextSharp 5.5.7 and PdfPTable.

I have a question about table border.
I need to customize the border (like the color or size for example). So I set UseVariableBorders to true.
In iText in action book, I saw that setting this method to true will make “the cell looks slightly bigger than the others : the thickness of the border is distributed equally inside and outside the cell dimensions”. This makes the outside border of the table looks smaller than the inside.

[image: Screenshot of the thicker line]

Other point, if you set for a cell, the border of the next cell will appear (in the example, the cell in the second column is merged vertically with a colspan of 2 and the last row cell is merged horizontally with a colspan of 2):

[image: Screenshot of the color]

Is there a good way to avoid that? (table event?)

Comment: This is a problem that is adequately solved in iText 7, but there's no C# version for iText 7 yet and we're still working on the documentation.

Comment: Thank you Bruno for the feedback. I will wait for the C# version.